# Get contents of DOM via PHP

Tags: php, html

I need to get the contents of a website through PHP, however, the content is only available when JavaScript is enabled. The workaround that I am using now is making an applescript to open the website in Safari, and selecting all of the page content, copying it to the clipboard, and pasting it.

Comment: Use firebug and see where the data comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best possible solution: ask the website owner for api/export access ;)

If that is not possible, you can only pray that you can analyze the requests that are initialized via JavaScript and imitate them.
(possible tools: firefox with firebug or tamper data plugin).

**Warning** the owner of the website might not like this approach, in fact, it may be disallowed to scrape the data automatically

Answer (score 3):

That will be really hard to achieve I guess. If you observe the JS on that page that is responsible for getting the content ready, you may discover its just another AJAX call that you may be able to call directly from your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by:

> the content is only available when JavaScript is enabled

Does the page pull data from somewhere via JS? Would it be easier to analyse where the data is coming from and access that place directly from PHP?